# How do people become captain in Captain's Mode

Tags: dota-2

I have been playing captain's mode in DOTA for one month, not a single time I was chosen as captain. On doing some research, I found that there is some button of **Become Captain**, since my internet connection is slow I am always second in loading the match. I tried google if I can see screenshot of that screen so I can see where that button is showed? But no luck. Dota forum, reddit, they all say *there is this button you should click to become captain* but I cant find exactly *where*.

If I am able to know where DOTA shows the become captain button I can start clicking at that place before it loads, so the chances of clicking after match loading are more?

Can anybody tell me where this option is ? Any screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may be the button you're referring too?

[image]

Comment: Good luck getting captain!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you play captain mode in RANKED games, the captain is always the one with the highest MMR rank, so you don't have a button. :D